# How can I communicate with a batch process?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, batch-file, daemon

I have a console application which has an infinite loop to make it run around the clock, it has database access as it should but the configurations are made via the database, which the process reads once and when it gets in the infinite loop it uses the config, so when I have to change any configuration I have to stop it change the info in the database and relaunch the batch process. My questions are:

- Is there any better way to make a batch process without infinite while?
- Communicate via the database, in my opinion, is not a good practice once you have to read always the data from the database even if it had not changed, I was thinking about a socket communication to set the variables(statics) inside the code so it can behave as it should. Is there any other way to do it which can be considered a best practice?

Thanks.

Comment: Please note that many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 0):

socket communication is an universal solution, but requires some work. If you have access to the computer where that batch process runs, you can simply read *System.in* in a loop and update configurations according to the values provided by the operator.

Comment: That is the big problem I don't have that kind of access since I will need to control that batch over the web, because it will be in another country.

Answer (score 0):

To have the console application occasionally consult the database while it is running (say, once every 5 minutes) is standard practice.

The trick, so the continued database access does not become a hindrance or reduce the application reliability, is that the application should simply continue with its Existing configuration if it temporarily cannot reach the database (instead of crashing or refusing to continue which is how people naturally write it the first time, until getting called out too many times at 3am).

No socket communication or new components required.